# Cloning prefab's data stop at a certain point. (Unity 2D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I wanted platforms to spawn above the camera and it does that, but it stops at a certain point. I'm trying to recreate doodle jump, and this was my code for generating platforms. (I'm also a beginner programmer if that means anything) Here's the code:

```
sing System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Generation : MonoBehaviour
{

    private float x;
    private float y;
    public GameObject bounce;
    private float lastY;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        x = gameObject.transform.position.x;
        y = gameObject.transform.position.y;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        lastY = GameObject.Find("Virtual Camera").GetComponent<LockCameraY>().lastY;

        SpawnBounce();
    }

    void SpawnBounce()
    {
        Debug.Log("Y value: "+y);
        Debug.Log("Camera position: "+lastY);
        if (y < lastY+5)
        {
            GameObject bounce1 = Instantiate(bounce, new Vector3(Random.Range(-5, 5), y + Random.Range(1, 3), 0), transform.rotation);
            x = bounce1.transform.position.x;
            y = bounce1.transform.position.y;
        }
    }
}
```

LastY is the last position the camera was at on the Y axis, and it gets updated very 0.1 seconds.
Bounce is the platforms name. The platforms spawning stop at around 15 on the y axis. Please ask for anymore clarification if needed. I have no idea what to do.

Comment: it works for me ... there seems to be something else involved that maybe disables this component?

Comment: Ok, I'll look...